# Fix file permission issue when mounting container from the jupyter docker stacks on Linux without removing ownership from the local user?

Tags: linux, docker, jupyter

#### The problem

We use the docker stacks containers as a convenient baseline image that can serve as a baseline dev environment for other containers with more tools. They are an integral part of our software development. Recently we moved off of Mac machines and on to linux where we experienced permission issues. These jupyter containers are the primary way that our firm interacts with python and R programming languages to avoid tricky webs of dependencies.

I want to run a container from the [jupyter docker stacks](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/running.html) on my Linux machine (I run a distro called [Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/) which is related to Ubuntu). The problem is that there are permission issues when running on linux where the user inside of the container does not have access to the mounted files by default.

[Note that this does not affect MacOS machines because they run docker differently](https://www.joyfulbikeshedding.com/blog/2021-03-15-docker-and-the-host-filesystem-owner-matching-problem.html)

#### Baseline

You can reproduce the issue by running this command

```bash
docker run \
  -p 8888:8888 \
  -v /path/on/local/machine/example_files:/home/jovyan/work \
  jupyter/base-notebook
```

When you go to `localhost:8888` in the browser and try to create a file in the container or save an existing file, you don't have permission to access the existing folder.

[image: Access denied within the jupyter window]

Examining the files closer they're all owned by root (UID=GID=0)

```
(base) jovyan@7680b47a5353:~/work$ ls -nash
total 20K
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 4    0   0 4.0K May  4 02:11 .
8.0K drwsrws--- 1 1000 100 4.0K May  4 02:22 ..
   0 -rw-rw-r-- 1    0   0    0 May  4 01:37 file2.txt
   0 -rw-rw-r-- 1    0   0    0 May  4 01:37 file.txt
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 2    0   0 4.0K May  4 02:11 .ipynb_checkpoints
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 2    0   0 4.0K May  4 01:37 subfolder
   0 -rw-r--r-- 1    0   0    0 May  4 02:11 untitled.txt
```

#### An unsatisfactory solution

The jupyter docker stacks website has [a solution](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/troubleshooting.html#permission-denied-when-mounting-volumes) to this which involves changing the ownership of the mounted drive and files to the local container user on startup.

(***Warning:** If you try the next command locally, it **will** mess up your file/folder ownership*)

In our case the code would be as follows where the UID and GID of the local user are both 1000. (found with the `id` command)

```bash
docker run \
  -u root \
  -e NB_UID=1000 \
  -e NB_GID=1000 \
  -e CHOWN_HOME=yes \
  -e CHOWN_HOME_OPTS="-R" \
  -p 8888:8888 \
  -v /path/on/local/machine/example_files:/home/jovyan/work \
  jupyter/base-notebook
```

When we go to `localhost:8888` in the browser, it looks good, we can create files and save existing ones in the working directory. We can see them on the mounted system.

The problem comes when we inspect the ownership of the files from the local machine (the one outside of our container). After running my docker command, the file the ownership for my files has all changed from my original UID and GID of 1000 to a UID and GID of 1009999

```
pegasaurus@pop-os:~/Documents/jupyter/file_permission_issue$ ls -nash example_files/
total 16K
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 4 100999 100999 4.0K May  3 18:11 .
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 6   1000   1000 4.0K May  3 18:03 ..
   0 -rw-rw-r-- 1 100999 100999    0 May  3 17:37 file2.txt
   0 -rw-rw-r-- 1 100999 100999    0 May  3 17:37 file.txt
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 2 100999 100999 4.0K May  3 18:11 .ipynb_checkpoints
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 2 100999 100999 4.0K May  3 17:37 subfolder
   0 -rw-r--r-- 1 100999 100999    0 May  3 18:11 untitled.txt
```

I can no longer make new files in the `/path/on/local/machine/example_files` directory on my local machine until I run `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /path/on/local/machine/example_files`

##### The Desired Outcome

I'd like to be able to run the `jupyter/base-notebook` or any other notebook from the jupyter docker stacks. I also want to retain my ability to access and create files on my local machine without having to change ownership back to myself each time. And without having  to set `chmod 777` on my folder or something silly like that.

Comment: I think that this question qualifies as on-topic because it centers around docker and jupyter which are "[software tools commonly used by developers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)". If it wasn't clear that this was needed for software development, I have edited the post to add "[programming context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/420218#420218) to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### My Solution

This is the solution that I came up with. If you have something, better, I'll give you the internet points fair and square...

To start up the container, I use the following `docker run` command

```bash
docker run \
  -u root \
  -e NB_USER="root" \
  -e NB_UID=0 \
  -e NB_GID=0 \
  -e NOTEBOOK_ARGS="--allow-root" \
  -p 8888:8888 \
  -v /path/on/local/machine/example_files:/home/root/work \
  jupyter/base-notebook
```

or the equivalent `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  jupyter-base:
    user: root
    environment:
      NB_USER: "root"
      NB_UID: 0
      NB_GID: 0
      NOTEBOOK_ARGS: --allow-root
    image: "jupyter/base-notebook"
    ports: 
      - "8888:8888" 
    volumes:
      - /path/on/local/machine/example_files:/home/root/work
```

When you go to `localhost:8888`, you can alter files and create new ones without a problem.

When you look at the files from your local machine (`ls -nash`), you see that the associated UID and GID of the files owner has not changed from their original values of 1000 and 1000.

```
pegasaurus@pop-os:~/Documents/jupyter/file_permission_issue$ ls -nash example_files/
total 24K
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 4 1000 1000 4.0K May  3 19:17 .
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 6 1000 1000 4.0K May  3 18:03 ..
   0 -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000    0 May  3 17:37 file2.txt
   0 -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000    0 May  3 17:37 file.txt
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000 4.0K May  3 19:16 .ipynb_checkpoints
4.0K drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000 4.0K May  3 17:37 subfolder
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000    8 May  3 19:17 untitled1.txt
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000    9 May  3 19:17 untitled.txt
```